# Opening webbrowser in Private mode to avoid Caching

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-webbrowser

I have created a flask application which run continuously and because of this, it can potentially overload the browser cache. Since the flask app is just filling out forms and it stays on 24/7, the responses could keep piling up and storing in the cache. I figured that if I run it in private mode then there would be no caching issues at all. I am using webbrowser to open the flask app.

```
webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I also tried the following but it then says 'chrome' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Same for 'google-chrome' or 'chrome-stable':

```
import os
os.system("chrome -incognito http://example.com")
```

I know you could probably do the following to open in private mode:

```
import webbrowser
url = 'www.google.com'
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)
```

However, I have bundled my entire flask application into an exe using pyinstaller and it can be used on any windows computer. But I will not know the chrome_path on that computer so how can I open webbrowser in private mode without knowing the path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Private browsing is not your fundamental problem.
You explained what you really care about is browser caching.

Use a `Cache-Control: max-age=600` header to limit lifetime to ten minutes.
Or use a HTML META tag to accomplish the same thing.

EDIT

When you said you were concerned about
"potentially overload the browser cache"
it sounded like the *amount* of material
was slowing down the browser.
You revealed little about your browsing pattern,
including whether it was GET or POST.

If you don't want the browser to remember
filled in form data, use the [autocomplete](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-autocomplete) attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="/myform" autocomplete="off">
```

To avoid [XY syndrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), you may want to ask a new question
that specifies a new set of parameters.

Comment: I tried ```<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no=store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />``` but the browser still remembered my inputs after I submitted a form. When I test it out manually in private browser, it does not remember any inputs.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question. To clarify, my flask app is just the user filling out forms and it stays on 24/7. I noticed the responses are being recorded by the cache (because it autofills that response the next time) in the browser, so I think that the cache is could get overloaded at some point since the form never turns off.